# Cannot seem to loop through nested associative array

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

I have googled to no avail I am missing something so fundamental I can't see it.

I have the following array

```
$this->links = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'http://maps.doc.govt.nz/Viewer/Index.html?viewer=rwa',
    'text' => 'DOC maps: Discover the outdoors ',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'https://booking.doc.govt.nz/',
    'text' => ' ',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'https://booking.doc.govt.nz/',
    'text' => ' Book Great Walks, selected huts, campsites and more.  ',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'https://careers.doc.govt.nz/jobtools/jncustomsearch.searchResults?in_organid=18174&in_searchBut=Search',
    'text' => 'Jobs at DOC ',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'http://blog.doc.govt.nz/',
    'text' => ' Conservation blog ',
  )....
```

I am trying to loop through it with this

```
foreach ($this->links as $arrayId) 
            {
            print "Link {\n";
            foreach ($arrayId as $linktitle=>$linkdetail)
                {
                echo 'link: -'.$linktitle .'<br/> bit'.$linkdetail;
                }
            }
```

But I am getting a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error. I really don't know why its not working, I have also tried every variation I can think of?? Still getting the same error?

UPDATE I dump the variable and $links is described as an array however when I add an is_array condition it returns false??????

```
        var_dump($links); 

- string 'array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'http://www.iana.org/domains/example',
    'text' => 'More information... ',
```

---

```
if (is_array($links))
{
    echo "Its an array";

} - does not return
```

Comment: `$this` is refer to object or class, where it is ?

Comment: $this is my class (a view). I have removed $this but still getting the same error

Comment: your variable `$links` is `string` not `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$this->links` is a string. you need it to be an array. if you cannot change is to array where you are generating it you can try the following. I **don't recommend** the usage of `eval()`, and it must be used as a last resort only.

```
$alinks=array();
eval('$alinks='.$this->links.';');
foreach ($alinks as $arrayId) 
        {
        print "Link {\n";
        foreach ($arrayId as $linktitle=>$linkdetail)
            {
            echo 'link: -'.$linktitle .'<br/> bit'.$linkdetail;
            }
        }
```

**Warning:** The `eval()` language construct is **very dangerous** because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. **Its use thus is discouraged.** If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention **not to pass any user provided data** into it without properly validating it beforehand.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: AAaaargh I using var_export to echo the dump and I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok but it is possible that the code that generates the value for $this->links is doing so erroneously. Try doing a print_r or var_dump of $this->links just before the first foreach and then do the same for the $arrayId before the second foreach and it may show you what is causing the problem. The only thing I can think of is that $this->links is not actually an array because of something previously not generating the data for it or assigning it correctly.

Comment: Thanks but I can var_dump the array fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove **$this** as egig has mentioned if you are not using a class and try the following:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 0);

$links = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'url' => 'http://maps.doc.govt.nz/Viewer/Index.html?viewer=rwa',
    'text' => 'DOC maps: Discover the outdoors ',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'url' => 'https://booking.doc.govt.nz/',
    'text' => ' ',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'url' => 'https://booking.doc.govt.nz/',
    'text' => ' Book Great Walks, selected huts, campsites and more.  ',
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'url' => 'https://careers.doc.govt.nz/jobtools/jncustomsearch.searchResults?in_organid=18174&in_searchBut=Search',
    'text' => 'Jobs at DOC ',
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    'url' => 'http://blog.doc.govt.nz/',
    'text' => ' Conservation blog ',
  )
);

foreach ($links as $arrayId)
{
        print "Link {\n";
        foreach ($arrayId as $linktitle=>$linkdetail)
        {
                echo 'link: -'.$linktitle .'<br/> bit'.$linkdetail;
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have removed $this and added the error reporting but still getting the same error. I did a var_dump to get my print out of the array so it is rendering fine?

Comment: @redstubble: Can you please post the entire array?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$this->links = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'http://maps.doc.govt.nz/Viewer/Index.html?viewer=rwa',
    'text' => 'DOC maps: Discover the outdoors ',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'https://booking.doc.govt.nz/',
    'text' => ' ',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'https://booking.doc.govt.nz/',
    'text' => ' Book Great Walks, selected huts, campsites and more.  ',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'url' => 'https://careers.doc.govt.nz/jobtools/jncustomsearch.searchResults?in_organid=18174&in_searchBut=Search',
    'text' => 'Jobs at DOC '
  ));

echo "<pre>";

for($i=0;$i<=count($this->links)-1;$i++)
{
    foreach($this->links[$i] as $value)
    {
        print_r($value);
        echo "<br>";


    }
}
?>
```